# Ok to ask questions below the "graduate" level?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've noticed that a lot of tag descriptions say questions should be at the graduate level or higher. I've been doing a lot of review lately (I have a bachelor's in math and I'm starting to delve in to computer science and stats), and find myself asking questions well below that level, but no-one seems to mind. Rather, people have been incredibly helpful and seem happy to lend a hand.

So I'm curious what the general consensus is on how welcome less advanced questions are. It seems like no matter how far you go, you still find yourself doubling back and questioning/reinvestigating the fundamentals you've been building on.

Comment: From the [About](http://math.stackexchange.com/about) page: "**Mathematics** *is a question and answer site for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields.*" :-)

Comment: One might go further and say that *much of the point of the site* is to allow questions below the graduate level to be asked.

Comment: +1 for "questioning/reinvestigating the fundamentals" no matter how far you go!

Comment: I think you may have confused math.stackexchange with mathoverflow.  At mathoverflow they basically only want research questions and put an emphasis on questions that might come up in graduate level texts.  As others have pointed out, *all* levels come as acceptable for math.stackexchange.

Comment: I wish physics SE would take a leaf from this book.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes. The site is for all levels.

Do note that [set-theory] has [elementary-set-theory] and [number-theory] has [elementary-number-theory], both for undergrad level questions.

Of course that some questions in undergrad level might be suitable for the "advanced" tags as well.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ivan Also--Don't be too afraid of mistagging a question--there are plenty of people here with tag edit privileges who will retag the question if you've done something "really wrong."  Of course, don't take this as a free pass to not tag or to tag poorly... `:)`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an recent example of an question that may be even below highschool level:
[How do I rewrite -100+1/2 as the mixed number -99 1/2?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313800/how-do-i-rewrite-1001-2-as-the-mixed-number-99-1-2/313812#313812)

So even (re)investigating the fundementals of mixed numbers is totally accepted ;)